# Jquery accessing divs problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('div#searchResult > div#searchResultItem > div#item').hover(function() 
{
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

Hi guys. Im doing a quick application on what i have learned on a tutorial site for jquery. I think of other ways on applying the functionality and came up with this code.
The problem is I can't access the #item div content. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks and more power to stackoverflow guys. Cheers!

```
<div id="searchResult">
     <div id="searchResultItem"> 
        <div id="item">Some item</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your html structure.

Comment: well, theoretically if you were really looking for #item you wouldn't have to use any other selector, since ids are unique... ;)  i think what you're looking for are classes.

Comment: My guess agrees with nathan, I think you are possible confusing id attributes with classes?

Comment: @Mitch, the context is about accessing divs inside divs.

Comment: ids are used to element specific types and classes are for those elements that shares a common attribute in terms of color/font/etc.

Comment: @Zend_Newbie_Dev, while i understand what you're doing with the id's, it is improper.  id's, by nature, should be unique in a given page.  if they are generated programatically, think about appending a counter to the end.  if you are using them for general styling, don't.  add a second class.  and then a third if necessary.  use the id field only to uniquely identify a particular element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should wait for DOM structure fully loaded, and apply your script after that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div#searchResult > div#searchResultItem > div#item').hover(function() 
   {
      alert($(this).text());
   });
})
```

And if you want not only text of #item, it could be better to use .html() method:

```
alert($(this).html());
```

BTW, check if #searchResult div hover triggering.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div#searchResult').hover(function() 
   {
      alert($(this).find('div#item').text());
   });
})
```

if it is, then I suppose it's css and markup problem. Maybe some div's insufficient overflow or height properties.

Comment: Then..maybe your div#item isn't properly hovered? It can be if it's not fully overflowed or has 0 height or display inline property, or something else. Try in another browser or show your css-styles for your markup

Answer (score 2):

see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQamB/2/) for a working example.

i basically copy-pasted what you posted, so you must be leaving something out.  i would suggest that you do as one of the other posters has said and use the $(document).ready() event to ensure the dom is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply on all of them it should be a coma separated right

```
$('#searchResult','#searchResultItem','#item').hover(function() 
{
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: i don't think that's what he wants at all, and the comma's should be inside the quotes anyway.  the > symbol is an immediate child selector.

Comment: @Zend_Newbie_Dev, please post any question updates in the question itself, not in the comments.  this will allow for proper formatting and such.